# Thoughts affect water?

Tags: water, masuru-emoto

I  happened to come across the experiment conducted by Masuru Emoto in which he claims that thoughts affect water. He claims to have taken pictures under a microscope before and after applying mental stimulus(love, hate). Below is the link.

[Dr. Masaru Emoto's Water Molecule Experiments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWAuc9GIvFo)

My question is, is that true what he discovered? I looked up the validity of the experiment and couldn't find anything, and thought maybe someone might enlighten me here.

And if the experiment is true, how?